# MySQL database search php issue

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have written basic script for search database of my current php site. its showing me data even if I do not write any word in search box as well it show many row same for any keyword. as well its not getting refreshed for new search. Please check and let me know what I have missed in this ?
Thanks

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<?php

include("config.php");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');

$q=$_POST['q'];
$q=mysql_escape_string($q);
$q_fix=str_replace(" ","%",$q); // Space replacing with %
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT qu_text FROM quotes WHERE qu_text LIKE N'%$qu_text%'");
}
?>
<html>

<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="q" /> <input type="submit" value=" Search " />
</form>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$title=$row['qu_text'];
echo '<div>'.$title.'</div>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is wrong.

The variable `$qu_text` is not initialised anywhere.

```
SELECT qu_text FROM quotes WHERE qu_text LIKE N'%%'
```

You have added wild card like on `$q_text`. It does not get any value, therefore, it is showing all results.

As the query is becoming:

**Correct Query:**

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT qu_text FROM quotes WHERE qu_text LIKE '%$q%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing a wild card search - if $qu_text is empty your query will return everything.  If your requirement is to show nothing if the search parameter is blank.  Then put a condition in and do not even perform the query if $qu_text is null or empty.

Also I think you need to pass $q_fix not $qu_text to the query.

Comment: I agree. At least trim and check for input such as: `if(trim($_POST['q'] != ''){ $sql .....}`